# PHP fopen from windows to external unix server

Tags: php, windows, unix, fopen

I have a trouble with fopen(), the function returns "failed to open stream: No such file or directory" when i am trying to write file which is on unix server.
My PHP application is running on Windows.

This is the code where I am using the fopen function :

```
$path = "/212.120.15.80/tmp/NMJ.pdf"; //Path to unix server
$url = $_FILES [$fileElementName] ['tmp_name'];


     $newfname = $path;

     $file = fopen ( $url, "rb" );
     if ($file) {
        $newf = fopen ( $newfname, "wb" );
        $fopen = $newf;

        if ($newf) {
            while ( ! feof ( $file ) ) {
                fwrite ( $newf, fread ( $file, 1024 * 8 ), 1024 * 8 );
            }
        }
     }
     if ($fopen === false) {
        $return_fopen = 'Fichier non téléchargé';
     } else {
        $return_fopen = 'Le fichier a été déposé sur le serveur';
     }

     if ($file) {
        fclose ( $file );
     }
     if ($newf) {
        fclose ( $newf );
     }
```

I have write/read access on the tmp directory.

This code works when I am writing a file on a windows server with this path : "\\Example/share"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it is worth checking if file exists before trying to load its content. Use `file_exists()` for this case.
Then, your path is set to a local file. Use something like

```
$path = "http://212.120.15.80/tmp/NMJ.pdf"
```

Comment: Thanks for your advices. 

I cannot use http protocol because it does not allow to use fopen in write mode

Comment: Eventually, I change my code to be able to use "http" protocol
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I post my code for people who need it

```
$docup = 'http://212.120.15.80'
$filename = $_FILES [$fileElementName] ['name'];

$ch = curl_init ( $docup );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $docup . "/uploadfilescript.php" );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array (
        'file' => '@' . $url,
        'filename' => $filename 
) );

if (curl_exec ( $ch ) === FALSE) {
        $return = 'Le fichier n\' a pas pu être téléchargé';
} else {
    curl_exec ( $ch );
    $return = 'Le fichier a été déposé sur le serveur';
}

curl_close ( $ch );
```